# How to create an integer data type with over 1 billion digits in c

Tags: c

I'm working on a prodgect in which I need a huge number, 1 billion digits.  I'm writing in c, though I'll take answers from objective-c.

Also, I'm wondering about this function/data type I found: Biginteger.

I would like to know what language people use this in and if it will help my problem.

Please respond, 
Frederick

Comment: Billion digits, are you sure about that?

Comment: 1 billion digits is going to far more than 200MB of memory. A the processing time... forget it.

Comment: Perhaps he means values greater than 1 billion?

Comment: I can't help, but once you accomplish it, please write down your number here. Just curiosity.

Comment: is it american or si billion?

Comment: *Need* it for what?  80 digits is enough for the number of atoms in the observable universe.  There are not enough atoms in your PC to handle such a value!

Comment: @Clifford A modern computer should be able to store such a value just fine.  It would likely take a very, very long time to calculate something with it, however.

Comment: @Sydius: It was not intended as a serious point; just to get a sense of scale.

Comment: Clifford, It is even not enough to store number of atom states in a single cup of coffee!

Answer (score 3):

There is the [GMP bignum library](http://gmplib.org/), if that's what you are asking.
<sub>(Seems to be offline at the moment: [cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:6KSxN_o6hIYJ%3agmplib.org/+bignum&cd=2&hl=en&ct=clnk&client=ubuntu))</sub>

Comment: libgmp will call `abort()` if your number has a billion digits, I think.. ;-) Very bad design for a library.

Comment: @R.:  I am not sure it matters much due to the computational feasibility of such a number!  When an eighty-digit integer is sufficient to count the number of atoms in the observable universe, what would be the possible application of a billion digit integer!?